# Enforce https on portainer with cert-manager and letsencrypt after initial setup

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I have a running k3s cluster with portainer and helm, and I just got cert-manager with letsencrypt set up as a `ClusterIssuer`

Now I would like to enforce https and use the certificate I created for portainer:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: portainer-tls-secret
  namespace: portainer
spec:
  secretName: portainer-tls-secret
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  subject:
    organizations:
      - <redacted>
  commonName: portainer.k8s.mydomain.tld
  isCA: false
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    encoding: PKCS1
    size: 4096
  usages:
    - server auth
    - client auth
  dnsNames:
    - portainer.k8s.mydomain.tld
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    group: cert-manager.io
```

This works beautifully:
`kubectl get Certificate --all-namespaces`

> ```
> NAMESPACE      NAME                                  READY   SECRET                                    AGE
> portainer      portainer-tls-secret                  True    portainer-tls-secret                      11m
> ```

But according to [the documentation](https://docs.portainer.io/advanced/ssl#using-your-own-ssl-certificate-on-kubernetes-via-helm) I have to supply it with a parameter:

`helm install -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer --set tls.existingSecret=portainer-tls-secret`

(OR upload a single file using the settings, which I doubt very much will autorenew using cert-manager)

As I understand it, the `--set <variablename>=<value>` is for setting environment variables - can I just "deploy" it by running the helm chart? - even though it is not installed via helm:

> ```
> $ helm upgrade -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer --set tls.existingSecret=portainer-tls-secret
> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "portainer" has no deployed releases
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My not-very-elegant solution was to uninstall portainer

```sh
kubectl delete namespace portainer
kubectl delete ClusterRoleBinding portainer
```

and reinstall it using helm:

```sh
helm upgrade --install --create-namespace -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer \
    --set tls.force=true \
    --set tls.existingSecret=portainer-tls-secret
```